# Errors occurred in initializing language server

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[I cannot use suggestion for Java in VS code anymore :((](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Luqu.png)
VS Code sasid that "Errors occurred in initializing language server", I don't understand, please help me :((, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the code project to another directory and reopen it. This should solve the problem.